# how to add a formula/text at the end of every table cell in microsoft word

Tags: ms-word

I am working on a macro where i need to add a formula at the end of every cell in table in Microsoft word.I need to know whether it is possible to add a text or blank space at the end of the word for each table cell.

Answer (score 0):

you can loop through all cells of the table by doing somethin like this

```
Sub addStuffToTableCells()
    Dim oTable As Table
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer

    For Each oTable In ActiveDocument.Tables
        For x = 1 To oTable.Rows.Count
            For y = 1 To oTable.Columns.Count
                oTable.Cell(x, y).Select
                Selection.Text = "asdasd"
            Next y
        Next x
    Next oTable
End Sub
```